# Ambiguous SwitchParameter binding in PowerShell cmdlet

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I want to add two switch parameters to my custom PowerShell cmdlet like this:

```
[Parameter(Mandatory = false, ParameterSetName = "p1")]
public SwitchParameter switchOne { get; set; }

[Parameter(Mandatory = false, ParameterSetName = "p2")]
public SwitchParameter switchTwo { get; set; }
```

But when I run my cmdlet, it raises `AmbiguousParameterSet`, even if I don't specify any of them. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Do you have default parameter set specified in `Cmdlet` attribute?

Comment: No, I don't. I guess without the parameters the ambiguity would remain right?

Comment: Correct.  Without parameters passed, it's entirely ambiguous.  `[Cmdlet(DefaultParameterSet = "p1")]`

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Note in C# it is [`Cmdlet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.cmdletattribute) attribute, but not [`CmdletBinding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.cmdletbindingattribute) attribute.

Comment: @PetSerAl Thanks- edited.  I obviously don't write cmdlets in C#!

Comment: If I don't specify any switch parameter shouldn't it mean that the two of them are set in false?

Comment: @MauriR Not specifying switch parameter is not the same as explicitly specifying false for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the mandatory attribute to true if the switch uniquely indicates the use of a parameter set.

If this is the case then you may need to reconsider your use of parameters sets, each set should be unique, if you need a switch to indicate uniqueness then you probably don't need parameter sets.

However, without a full list of the parameters its difficult to say.

Comment: I removed both parameter set names and it worked. I guess the two parameter sets, although with different names, specified the same number and type of parameters (One mandatory, three strings and this two of type switchParameter).